# IndexedDB Users › IndexedDB current usage

Tags: indexeddb

I was wondering if there is a way or any report which is showing IndexedDB the number of usage on desktop and mobile browser. Something like how many API calls are made. Just trying to figure if it is used widely or not. Additionally, if anyone knows what is the reason for not being used.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering if there is a way or any report which is showing
>   IndexedDB the number of usage on desktop and mobile browser. Something
>   like how many API calls are made.

No, there is no such official report or market survey published which can give you exact or even approximate market share information.

> Just trying to figure if it is used widely or not.

**At this point of time, as per available information, it is the future ahead.**
W3C have few specifications for  web or browser storage like [WebSQL](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/), [IndexedDB](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/), [Web storage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/).

1. WebSQL:  It was predecessor of IndexedDB, and now deprecated. Since you are starting afresh, you **must not** consider using the same.
2. IndexedDB: This is the replacement of WebSQL and **future ahead for storing information in browser embedded database**.
3. Web storage: Storage option applicable for **small data in form of key-value pair**. It is not good for large amount of structured data, in these scenarios you should consider IndexedDB.

If you have to handle files (while is like client side file storage or file handling) then there is an API specs by W3C - [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/). It’s possibly the best solution for generated binary data such as images, audio, video and PDFs.

So, you can use **IndexedDB** API for database storage and **File API** for file storage.

Comment: [FileSystem API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_API) is [dead](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/). File API is not related to storage.

Comment: @hagrawal thanks for the answer, but I was asking just for the amount of call or usage statistics (doesn't need to be official), not interested in details about client side storage. Just found this https://www.sencha.com/blog/the-state-of-html5-development-in-the-enterprise/ so I guess there should be a more detailed survey or report somewhere. Obviously based on statistics Im interested in the pro's or con's of not being used widely.

Comment: @stefan Oh ok. Unofficial results are not to be trusted per se, especially when you working for some client. I have explained in my answer that at this point there is really no choice other than IndexedDB. WebSQL API is deprecated and Web Storage API is for small data storage and not in browser database. So, if you really want a browser database solution, then IndexedDB is the only solution left and way ahead. The link you provided, provides relative comparison of HTML 5 features and not about IndexedDB usage. There is no such report what you are expecting.

Comment: WARNING: browsers will trash your DB without any notice if they need to. There is no method (yet) of registering a URL to be notified before this happens to allow you to make a server-side backup or prompt the user for a decision. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Browser_storage_limits_and_eviction_criteria) only details Firefox behaviour but I suspect other browsers are the same.